# Overwriting Bootstrap Primary Button with external CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

Have the following CSS code and would like to get the bootstrap button to change from its default 'blue' color when the button is 'active' (meaning pressed down on) to value #954900; but it is staying blue and not changing.  Copied code from a tutorial and understand that you need to 'cover all cases' but what am I missing here?  Note: I made sure to include the external stylesheet AFTER bootstrap CSS link in head as well.  **Thanks** for all help..

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
outline: 0 none;}

.btn-primary {
background: #EC811C;
color: #ffffff;}

.btn-primary:hover , .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary  {
background: #F89F4A;}

.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
background: #954900;
box-shadow: none;}
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Search</button>
```

Comment: Try 'LoVe For HAte'. That is: a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover, a:active. (this should be the order)

Comment: Likely to be a specifity issue. Please share the relevant html and css that will enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good point @HiddenHobbes i have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to include your custome css after bootstrap also try adding !important after each rules to see if it help.
Like

```
.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
    background: #954900 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important; 
}
```

edit: as Krzysztof Dąbrowski say in his comment !important is not the right solution, it's more like a debugging trick to confirm that you are editing the right css rules. If it work with !important you should confirm that your CSS file is loaded AFTER the boostrap one as web browser give priority to the last read css rule.

if it doesn't solve your probleme please share more code.

Comment: Please, don't add `!mportant`. You should avoid it. In this case there's no need for this. If you place your CSS after Bottstrap, you won't need `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `Sass` version of `Bootstrap`, you can use `button-variant` mixin. If you have to use plain `CSS`, you can take a look at the contents of this mixin and write it in the exact same way in the same order. Then everything should be 100% compatible and covered.

The mixin is here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, this is what worked for me:

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
outline: 0 none;}
.btn-primary {
background: #EC811C;
color: #ffffff;}
.btn-primary:hover , .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary  {
background: #F89F4A;}
.btn-lg:active, .btn-lg.active, .btn-block:active, .btn-block.active, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active  {
background: #954900 !important; 
box-shadow: none !important;}
```